# way to unpack data within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that "packed" and I'm trying to find a way to unpack into multiple columns and rows:

input as a df with multiple list within a column

```
all_labels                 values                       labels                   
[A,B,C]          [[10,1,3],[5,6,3],[0,0,0]]            [X,Y,Z]
```

desired output: unpacked df

```
        X          Y             Z
A       10         1             3   
B       5          6             3  
C       0          0             0
```

I tried this for all_labels & labels column but not sure how to do it for values column :

`df.labels.apply(pd.Series)`
`df.all_labels.apply(pd.Series)`

Comment: So I assume this is just a toy example, what should happen if you have more rows?

Comment: yes just an example. However the original df only have 1 row but each column is a nested list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Setup

```
packed = pd.DataFrame({
    'all_labels': [['A', 'B', 'C']],
    'values': [[[10, 1, 3], [5, 6, 3], [0, 0, 0]]],
    'labels': [['X', 'Y', 'Z']]
})
```

---

#### Keep It Simple

```
pd.DataFrame(packed['values'][0], packed['all_labels'][0], packed['labels'][0])

    X  Y  Z
A  10  1  3
B   5  6  3
C   0  0  0
```

---

#### `rename` and `dict` unpacking

The columns are so close to the argument names of the dataframe constructor, I couldn't resist...

```
rnm = {'all_labels': 'index', 'values': 'data', 'labels': 'columns'}
pd.DataFrame(**packed.rename(columns=rnm).loc[0])

    X  Y  Z
A  10  1  3
B   5  6  3
C   0  0  0
```

---

#### Without `rename` and `list` unpacking instead

Making sure to list the column names in the same order the arguments are expected in the `pandas.DataFrame` constructor

```
pd.DataFrame(*packed.loc[0, ['values', 'all_labels', 'labels']])

    X  Y  Z
A  10  1  3
B   5  6  3
C   0  0  0
```

---

---

#### Bonus Material

The `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict` method will return a dictionary that looks similar to this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(*packed.loc[0, ['values', 'all_labels', 'labels']])

df.to_dict('split')

{'index': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 'columns': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
 'data': [[10, 1, 3], [5, 6, 3], [0, 0, 0]]}
```

That we could wrap in another dataframe constructor call to get back something very similar to what we started with.

```
pd.DataFrame([df.to_dict('split')])

       index    columns                                data
0  [A, B, C]  [X, Y, Z]  [[10, 1, 3], [5, 6, 3], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Why do I always overt hink these types of problem?   Just use the dataframe constructor. Of course. Meanwhile,  Scott is over here practicing dataframe judo.  Stack, swap, unstack, flip, transpose.   1.. 2.. 3... match over!

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston that made me chuckle.